# RegExp (^|\\?|&) in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

Could you please help me understand this javascript RegExp :

```
cbreg = new RegExp('((^|\\?|&)' + cbkey + ')=([^&]+)')
// where cbkey is a string
```

I am confused by the `(^|\\?|&)` portion. What could that mean?

Thanks !

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp

Comment: In case anyone's interested, the code is from here https://github.com/ded/reqwest/blob/master/src/reqwest.js#L76 and means callback regex, and parses the JSONP callback function name from a query string

Comment: Thank you for the reference I think I read the article about Regular expressions on MDN instead of the one on RegExp. And also @Esailija you're right, the code sample comes from ded/reqwest. Thanks for mentioning it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well first of all given that the regex is created from a string literal the double backslashes become only a single backslash in the resulting regex (because that's how escaping works in a string literal):

```
(^|\?|&)
```

The `|` means OR, so then you have:

```
^    - start of line, or
\?   - a question mark, or
&    - an ampersand
```

A question mark on its own has special meaning within a regex, but an escaped question mark matches an actual question mark.

The parentheses means it matches one of those choices before matching the next part of the regex. Without parens the third choice would include the next part of the expression (whatever is in `cbkey`).

Answer (score 2):

It means either (`|`) the start of the string (`^`), a literal question (`\?` because the question mark needs to be escaped in regexes and `\\?` because the backslash needs to be escaped in strings) mark or an ampersand (`&`).

Comment: End of string is `$`, not `&`.

Comment: Even if it were `$` it wouldn't make any sense since there's more stuff coming after it.

Answer (score 1):

`|` means "OR".  So that means: `^` (start of line) OR `?` OR `&`.

Answer (score 1):

It searches for the block (the parentheses mean a block) which must start (^ = must start with) with character '?' or (| = or) character '&'.